# Evitar persistir dados ao fazer refresh

Tags: mvc

Estou gravando um log de histórico de opções acessadas, ao fazer *refresh* na página ele está duplicando os dados. Como faço para persistir somente na requisição?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Começe fazendo um [tour] e veja também [ask]. Sua pergunta está muito genérica e provavelmente será fechada caso você não inclua mais detalhes a partir do link [edit].

Comment: Qual linguagem você está usando? Qual *framework*? Qual servidor? Quais códigos implementam as ações que realizam tal duplicação? Pode por favor editar sua pergunta e colocar mais detalhes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independente da linguagem a solução da questão da pra ser resolvida apenas com informações do `request` enviadas pelo navegador. Neste caso vamos utilizar o `chrome` e `firefox`, pois ambos adicionam um novo **header** quando o usuário der um <kbd>refresh</kbd> ou <kbd>f5</kbd>, esse **header** é o `Cache-Control` com um valor de `max-age 0`.

#### Implementação em `ASP.NET MVC`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var cacheControl = Request.Headers["Cache-Control"];

    if (cacheControl != null) // opcional o `Equals("max-age=0")`
    {
        // "É refresh"
    } else {
        // Pode salvar o log
    }
    // restante do código
}
```

O `internet explorer` adiciona um parâmetro na requisição dependendo da versão, vai de você ver qual você quer abranger e adaptar essa solução.

Comment: Estou usando o IE11 como consigo obter esse parâmetro? No chrome funcionou.

Comment: @AlUnserAlbuquerque Estou no trabalho agora e não vou conseguir reproduzir o teste pra verificar a diferença, mas se você tiver com tempo livre faça uma iteração no  `Request.Headers` e `Request.Param` pra tenta notar alguma diferença quando é f5 ou não. Se você observar utilizando `Chrome` o `Request.Headers` aumenta um parâmetro

Comment: Chegando em casa posso tentar achar a diferença e te falar.

Comment: Então Maicon no chrome ele adiciona                Request.Headers["CACHE-CONTROL"] quando dou refresh na página porém eu queria ter esse controle também no IE11.

Comment: notou algo no IE?

Comment: procura pelo pragma

Comment: No IE11 ele não adiciona.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995009/ie-adding-http-header-pragma-no-cache

Comment: Maicon no IE o Cache-Control vem privado não  sei se é  por esse motivo q não  consigo obter ele

Comment: @AlUnserAlbuquerque estou testando aqui também e não consegui ver alguma diferença, só uma dúvida você que bloquear chamar o mesmo action mais de uma vez?

Comment: Então o meu propósito é salvar um log quando o usuário entrar em uma determinada página e se por algum motivo ele der refresh eu não devo salvar no banco.